# This SparkContext may be an existing one. error

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using spark2.0 in notebook, this is the initial set up:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("NewApp") \
   .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "600g") \
   .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
   .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize",10737418240) \
   .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval",10000000) \
   .getOrCreate()


/usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
167                     for key, value in self._options.items():
168                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 169                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
170                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
171                     for key, value in self._options.items():

/usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
292         with SparkContext._lock:
293             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 294                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
295             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
296 

/usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
113         try:
114             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
 --> 115                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
116         except:
117             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

  /usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
166 
167         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 168         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
169         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
170         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

     /usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/context.py in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
231         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
232         """
  --> 233         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
234 
235     @classmethod

     /usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1399         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1400         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1401             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  1402 
  1403         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark-2.0.1/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
320             else:
321                 raise Py4JError(

     Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
   : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10737418240"
at                 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getInt$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getInt$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:375)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getInt(SparkConf.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.maxMessageSizeBytes(RpcUtils.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.<init>(MapOutputTracker.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:284)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:420)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
```

how could I solve this problem? I tried SparkContext.stop(), but it gives:
TypeError: stop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Another one  question is my initial set up is getOrCreate() to my understanding if there is one then get it, if not create it, it still give this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source of the error:

> : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10737418240"
>   at                 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)

10737418240 is larger than `Int.MaxValue`(2147483647). Use smaller value when calling:

```
.config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", ...) \
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix JAVA_HOME and restart cmd.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30016639)